# python re string of length(3-4) max

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract from text any 3 or 4 consecutive numbers only, not longer, here's an example

```
text = 'abc 123\n ab3245ss a234234234234\n 12'
```

I'm trying this:

```
re.findall(r'\d{3,4}', text)
```

What I'm expecting:

```
['123', '3245']
```

What I'm getting:

```
['123', '3245', '2342', '3423', '4234']
```

Comment: Please try this `(?<=\D)(\d{3,4})(?=\D)`

Comment: Yes, this works, you may explain in an answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

When using a positive lookahead `(?=\D)` or lookbehind `(?<=\D)`, there has to be a character present.

If you also want to match for example only 123, you can assert what is on the left and on the right is not a digit using a negative lookahead and lookbehind.

```
(?<!\d)\d{3,4}(?!\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8smdEg/1)

Answer (score -1):

Please try below regex. This will take numbers that surrounded with a non-digit.

```py
(?<=\D)(\d{3,4})(?=\D)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/e6xbvT/1)

**Edit**: Use `re.findall(r"(?:\D|^)(\d{3,4})(?:\D|$)",text)` to also match numbers that may occur in start and end of the line.

Answer (score -1):

```
text = 'abc 123\n ab3245ss a234234234234\n 12'

re.findall(r'(?<=\D)(\d{3,4})(?=\D)',text)
```

Answer (score -1):

As a number of answers are suggesting, you need to explicitly check that the characters before and after your string are not numbers.

But additionally, there might not be **any** character before or after the number. Let's handle that as well.

```
re.findall(r"(?:^|[^\d])(\d{3,4})(?:$|[^\d])", text)
#            ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑         ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
#          handles the             handles the
#          leading character       trailing character
```